# Creating a list of words from Wikipedia

Tags: python, words

I am creating a game and I need a dictionary (a list of plain words in this case) containing not only the base form, but all the others as well. In this case the language is Italian and, for example, the verbs have many forms and nouns too.

Since the language is very irregular, I want to get the words from a huge source which may contain them all. At first I thought about Wikipedia: I would download every article, extract the text, and filter the words.

This will take so much time that I'd like to know whether there could be better solutions, both in terms of time and completeness of the list.

Comment: You don’t have to download each article, if you think about a crawler. There are [dumps of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Other_languages).

Comment: @Aufziehvogel: Great suggestion, this will speed up the process!

Comment: See this [HugeWordList](http://www.wuala.com/Lifehacker%20Fun%20File%20Swap/Documents/Huge%20Word%20List.txt?lang=en). The words are from many languages though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a Linux system you might want to look in /usr/share/dict/words.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Linux. Unfortunately that file contains only the base words and it's very hard to generate the others starting from those (grammar rules and all the exceptions...).

Comment: in the same mindset, you could also use aspell dictionary: `aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > english`, which should expand to all the word-form it knows

Comment: @rubik Are you sure, my english dictionary has masses of words. For example: grep 'ing$' /usr/share/dict/words has a lot of results.

Comment: Ok, it's sufficient. Thanks!